# Canonically conjugate variable of rapidity

Tags: special-relativity, fourier-transform, phase-space, integrable-systems, canonical-conjugation

Does the rapidity $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ have a canonically conjugate variable? More specifically, for some smooth function $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, by Plancherel's theorem we have (up to some Fourier transform coefficient constant)
\begin{equation}
\int f(\theta) \overline{f(\theta)} d\theta = \int |f(p)|^2 dp.
\end{equation}

But what is this variable $p$? Does it have a physical meaning?

This paper https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.13.99 seems to suggest that the conjugate variable to rapidity is the boost direction, but it has an air of 'old' physics to it that makes it not so easy to follow for me. If this is true, in one spatial dimension, would $p$ then correspond to direction? Either left or right.

Comment: I'm not sure what your difficulty is with O'Raifeartaigh's paper; it seems to cover the relevant issues pretty clearly, tying the question to observables in the modern language of quantized field excitations.  Nor is it clear by what you mean by your last two sentences.

Comment: I suppose my difficulty is simply my ineptitude. In the last two sentences I'm basically asking what should a longitudinal boost in one spatial direction mean?

Comment: Isn't rapidity equal to the boost angle by definition?

Comment: Yep, you're correct. I meant boost direction, sorry. I've edited it now.

Comment: Bernice & Lochlainn's paper is crushingly pedagogical, so there is no point in "explaining" it. If you wanted a *loose* analogy, you might think of rapidity as some sort of hyperbolic "azimuth" angle, continuous but compact. And hence the $K_3$ boost as some sort of $J_z$, hence with discrete spectrum, so that $\Delta y \Delta k_3\geq \hbar/2$, as they take care to detail!